# How to filter objects between two dates in two seperate fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, date

I need to filter and get only objects that match these criteria,

1. Of property and value "aspectType": "Event Calendar".
2. Between dates from 10/15/2017 to 10/30/2017 (the date format is in mm/dd/yyyy)

   ```
   {
   "_id": "a5a88cf3-3791-41e7-b8ad-f016d22e58a0",
   "from_date": "10/26/2017",
   "to_date": "10/26/2017",
   "aspectType": "Event Calendar"
   }

   {
   "_id": "920ddc44-611e-4878-8d0c-b0d6efee1cd4",
   "from_date": "10/26/2017",
   "to_date": "10/26/2017",
   "aspectType": "Event Calendar"
   }

   {
   "_id": "54bcbfa5-f644-452b-865a-83a2fc3d0b7b",
   "from_date": "10/09/2017",
   "to_date": "10/10/2017",
   "aspectType": "Event Calendar",
   }
   ```

How to filter objects using MongoDB?

The code that I have written is,

```
{aspectType: "Event Calendar", $and:[{from_date: {$gte:10/15/2017}},{to_date:{$lte: 10/30/2017}}]}
```

Comment: You could probably start by making the strings "yyyy-mm-dd" at least, but they really should be BSON `Date`. Unless they are in that format, operators like `$gte` and `$lte` will not work as expected since the strings are not lexically ordered. Anyway, "start" needs to be less than provided and "end" needs to be greater than provided. It's an interview question I regularly use.

Answer (score 0):

mongo date queries support ISODate("2012-12-27T23:25:45.120Z").

try:

```
 $and:[{from_date: {$gte: ISODate("2012-10-15T00:00:00.000Z")}},{to_date:{$lte: ISODate("2012-10-30T00:00:00.000Z")}}
```